# Adding extra but non-aliased emails within GSuite

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-workspace-for-business

Have setup GSuite to handle emails for a certain domain name and have also added aliases via: **Google Admin -> Users -> {User} -> User Information -> Email Aliases**

However, what if I want to add an email address so that it *exists*, but *discard* or don't receive the email from it?

Use case is I need to setup a *noreply@example.com* email address but obviously don't want to add it as an alias.

Reason being is I have noticed sometimes in the past that some mail servers will reject mail if the email it's coming from doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GSuite support was surprisingly helpful and prompt after emailing them.

**Note:** Please read the important extra details at the bottom of my answer.

> You can achieve that in two ways, depending on what you prefer.
>
> **First option:** (Create a new user and a new organizational unit and set up a routing rule that rejects all incoming messages for that
>   organization):
>
> - Create a new user (in this case “noreply@example.com”) > Create a new organizational unit
>     (https://support.google.com/a/answer/182537?hl=en) > Move the new user
>     to the new organizational unit
>     (https://support.google.com/a/answer/182449?hl=en).
> - After that, go to Apps>G Suite>Gmail>Advanced settings.
> - On the left, select the new organization.
> - Scroll to the Routing setting in the Routing section, hover over the setting, and click Configure.
> - Make sure to enter a description for the rule at the top
> - Under "Messages to affect" select Inbound and Internal receiving
> - Under “For the above types of messages, do the following”, select “Reject message”
> - Optional: Add a rejection message
> - Click Save
> - Click Save again in the bottom right of the screen.
>
> Fore more information on routing, please visit
>   https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084?hl=en
>
> **Second option:** (Create an email alias and set up a filter that automatically delete every incoming email to that alias)
>
> - Create an email alias for one of the user (https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=en)
> - Create a filter with search criteria as follow:     To: email alias address
>     -Click on “Create filter” and tick “Skip the Inbox”, “Mark as read”, “Delete it”
>
> For more information about filters, please visit
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en.
>
> If you can create a new user, I would recommend the first option,
>   because the inbound messages will never reach the inbox and the sender
>   will get a rejection message.

**Some points of note:**

For *Option 1* you will incur extra monthly fees for adding an extra user unless you have available ones under your current plan.

Additionally, at least for my situation, I have decided it best that *Option 2* would probably be the better option as with *Option 1* it seems to act the same as if the mailbox doesn't exist, which is exactly the problem I am trying to avoid.

So to summarise:

- Option 1 may incur extra fees and will act as if the mailbox doesn't exist as the user will be returned a rejection message.
- Option 2 will not cost any extra and will "fail" silently.